# How can I make text right justified in a HTML element with display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner2">World</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
}
.inner1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: right;
}
.inner2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 5em
}
```

I would like the text inside the `inner1` class to be right justified. I thought the `text-align: right` would cause this to happen, but it does not.

How can I modify the above HTML and CSS to make the `inner1` text, "Hello", be right justified? Why does having `display: flex` affect this behavior?

Comment: Here's a related JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/pMF2m/1/

Comment: with `display:flex` on `.outer` the children become flex items.  no need to have `display:flex` on the inners.  Why do you want it? [**see this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Flexible_boxes_vocabulary) [**and this**](http://www.lynda.com/CSS-tutorials/Understanding-flex-property/116352/139392-4.html)

Comment: I don't know, I was just trying to be explicit. If you explain what flex does, and why I should remove it, I think it would make a good answer. I did notice you can right justify the text if you remove the `display: flex`. I'd still be curious to know why flex prevents right justify in the first place.

Comment: the links in my comment explain flex. its more than can be put in a comment

Comment: there is a tremendous amount of control you have over flex items (children of flex containers).  you need to read up on it.

Comment: I will Chris; I'm just staying you make want to summarize the information in an answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: so you want me to be your "cliffs notes" for css?  the answer to your specific question "Why does having display: flex affect this behavior?" is quite broad I suspect. I would venture a guess that using `display:flex` on the inners makes them "flex containers" rather than "flex items" and therefor follow the rules of "flex containters"

Comment: well isn't it right justified already…?

Comment: This question still has no answer.  How can we right-justify flex things?

Comment: @mareoraft Since you have placed a bounty I would let you choose an answer if I could. I will review the answers again after your bounty is done and select the one I think is best (probably the one with the most votes).

Comment: link from @Romulo is important resource for understanding, so droping it here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there. You just needed to add the `justify-content` property.

Add one line of code to your CSS:

```
.inner1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 5em;
    /* text-align: right; REMOVE; not necessary */
    justify-content: flex-end; /* NEW */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5qLdnk5p/1/

Here's a slightly enhanced demo to make the feature more noticeable:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5qLdnk5p/

---

From the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property):

> ***`justify-content`***
>
> The `justify-content` property aligns flex items along the main axis
>   of the current line of the flex container.
>
> ***`flex-end`***
>
> Flex items are packed toward the end of the line.

---

UPDATE

From the comment section:

> This is working for me. The only confusion for me is that it says that
>   `justify-content` aligns **flex-items**. Since when is the content (text)
>   itself considered a flex item? Moreover, is the `.inner1` div considered
>   a flex item, and will the entire div be moved around along the axis
>   too? – @mareoraft

The inline content in a flex container gets wrapped in an [anonymous flex item](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flex-items), which is able to inherit properties from the parent. However, anonymous items (like [anonymous block and anonymous inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#box-gen)) are *unselectable* and therefore *unstyleable*. So if you want to apply styles to the text consider wrapping it in a `<span>`, `<div>` or other element.

The `div` with class `.inner1`, as a child of the flex container (`.outer`), is a flex item. All flex item properties apply. `.inner1` also doubles as a (nested) flex container, so all flex container properties apply, as well.

Comment: This is working for me.  The only confusion for me is that it says that `justify-content` aligns **flex-items**.  Since when is the content (text) itself considered a flex item?  Moreover, is the `.inner1` div considered a flex item, and will the entire div be moved around along the axis too?

Comment: @mareoraft, I've updated my answer in response to you questions.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  I think it is important to understand that the `inner` container may not need to be `display: flex` at all, in which case Romulo's answer is preferable (IMHO).

Comment: @mareoraft, I focused on flexbox because (1) it represents the future of CSS layouts and alignment, (2) with `.inner1` as a flex container its children become flex items that can then benefit from flex properties, and (3) the OP seemed to be trying to better understand flexbox. But  `text-align: right` works, as well.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I modify the above HTML and CSS to make the inner1 text, "Hello", be right justified?

I know it's a simple example, but check if the following suits your needs:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
.left {
  text-align: right;
}
.right {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">left (right aligned)</div>
  <div class="right">right (left aligned)</div>
</div>
```

I recommend reading more about the `flex` property in [`A Complete Guide to Flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: This is very interesting.  It seems that the *outer* container treats its contents as flexible elements, but the *inner* containers do *not* treat their contents as flexible.  So you've got a combination of using flex and not using flex.  This is a very simple solution.  I am wondering what are the possible downsides to this?  Why might we WANT the inner containers to be flex or not flex?

Comment: I think this is the best solution as long as the innermost container doesn't need to be `display: flex`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be setting the following CSS:

Set the text aligning property to: `text-align: justify` and setting the read direction to: `direction:rtl`. Other answers are also very good answers.

These adjustments are [CSS2](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) based.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.inner1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 5em;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:justify;
}
.inner2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner2">World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this in my opinion is very bad solution. confusing and overly complicated.

Comment: Can you explain why? Only saying it is bad is not really helping @nakashu

Comment: sorry, the reasons where what was written there, that it is confusing etc. No one excepts an text direction change because of text alignment. And Mainly it could be solved by more native solution like Micahael_B anwer that I also upvoted.