# Flexbox - different alignment for two elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following markup:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="contact">email@example.com</div>

  <div class="branding">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  </div>

</div>
```

I essentially want the `contact` div to appear top-right of the window and the `branding` div to be centered on the remaining space on the page; i.e. I don't want the branding div to overlap the contact div at any point.

How would I achieve this with flexbox?

Update: here is an example of the desired layout: 
[image]

Comment: Do you have an image of the desired result? Is the centering vertical/horizontal or both...it's not clear from your question?

Comment: To reopen voters: this question is still unclear regarding layout details. Providing a desired layout would invalidate at least one and possibly all of the answers. Also let's try to avoid voting on questions where we have no experience on the tags...

Comment: I've added a layout to clarify the question

Comment: @TylerH, I'm not clear why the rush to close this question. The OP, in my view, clearly states the layout he is working to achieve. The key paragraph in the question, which I highlighted in my answer, is clear, unambiguous and straightforward. There are three parts to the layout as described in the paragraph. *What part is not clear?*

Comment: Also, I can understand that different people reading a question may not fully understand it (I admit that happens to me sometimes), but to blame the OP isn't always fair. For what it's worth, I don't feel the OP needed to edit the text or add an illustration.

Comment: @Michael_B Now that OP has added more details (via screenshot) of the layout he wants, it's no longer unclear. Before that, it wasn't clear whether OP wanted the divs displayed above one another, side by side, etc. Declaring he wanted them one above the other would invalidate my answer. Declaring he wanted them side by side would invalidate yours, etc.

Comment: Yeah, we discussed this before. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I essentially want the contact `div` to appear top-right of the window
>   and the branding `div` to be centered on the remaining space on the
>   page; i.e. I don't want the branding `div` to overlap the contact `div` at
>   any point.

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; } /* enable percentage height for flex container */

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%; /* give the flex container a height */
}

.contact {
    align-self: flex-end; /* align-right */
}

.branding {
    margin: auto; /* center branding div in container */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ky2k7jdr/4/)

With the code above, the contact `div` appears top-right of the window, the branding `div` is centered on the page, and there is no overlap at any time.

Comment: The branding div is clearly overlapping the contact div here.

Comment: You see how your red-bordered element is *within* the area of the green-bordered element? That is overlap. Your divs are 100% overlapping.

Comment: @TylerH, the green border represents to primary flex container. The `.contact` and `.branding` divs are in red borders. They don't overlap at any time, like required in the question.

Comment: I see, in that case I'm not sure why you have a green border in the first place, considering JSFiddle includes grey resizable borders around the iframe to begin with.

Comment: @TylerH, I added the key part of the question to my answer. The green border was included to outline the flex container, just as a matter of clarity and consistency (with the other bordered elements).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92980/discussion-between-tylerh-and-michael-b).

Comment: This is the best answer I could see. Only problem I had was that any padding of the `contact` div is squashed away when the viewport height is reduced. Otherwise does exactly what I asked

Comment: @harryg, the text in the `.contact` div is considered an [*anonymous flex item*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33139215/3597276) and is therefore unselectable, and therefore, unstyleable. Simply wrap the content in a `span`, then you can style it. Here's an updated demo with padding: http://jsfiddle.net/ky2k7jdr/3/

Comment: @harryg, there's actually an even more efficient way to achieve your layout. The nested flex container in the `content` div isn't necessary. I've updated the answer and demo.

Comment: This answer may be useful, as well: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, though I think it will be better once [CSS Grid Layouts](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-1/) gets better support.

The `lightgrey` background is just to show that the branding div is in fact taking up the rest of the space. As you can see, there's no overlap.

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.branding {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="contact">email@example.com</div>
    <div class="branding">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an external [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/8px4opcq/), too.

Comment: Maybe it's my browser (Chrome 46) but there is no centering there. The branding and content appear side-by-side and are both aligned at the top of the page

Comment: @harryg I missed that keyword; the branding div's content is centered now. As for being side by side; you didn't specify in your question how you wanted them to be laid out; side-by-side or one over the other, as Paulie_D mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

**COLUMNS**

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
    flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
}
div {
    -webkit-flex: none;
    flex: none;
}
.branding {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    align-items:center;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="contact">email@example.com</div>
    <div class="branding">
         <h1>Name</h1>

        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/21/)**

**ROWS**

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
div {
    -webkit-flex: none;
    flex: none;
}
.contact {   
    text-align:right;
}


.branding {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    align-items:center;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="contact">email@example.com</div>
    <div class="branding">
         <h1>Name</h1>

        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/22/)**

Comment: This doesn't work as the branding div is only centered horizontally, not vertically